# "Why can't I see?" or "Why I can't see?"?

Tags: word-order, questions, negation, subject-verb-inversion, wh-questions

Which of the following is correct?

> Why can't I see?
>   Why I can't see?

I am a bit confused, since both have inversion, negation and a "why" in the beginning.

Comment: See also [Why some questions are written in this funny way?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/59665/1506)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is, they're both correct. Just used in different situations.

"Why can't I see?" is a question, asking for the reason the "asker" is not perceiving something.

"Why I can't see" is a statement, not a question. In this case, the person who makes this statement is about to provide a reason for not perceiving something.

Comment: Why I can't see? has a question mark and is therefor not correct.

Answer (score 10):

> Why can't I see?

is a question.

> Why I can't see

may be used in a title.

> He knows why I can't see

is a statement.

Answer (score 4):

> ***why***
>
> 1. Used in questions to ask the reason for or purpose of sth
> 2. Used to give or talk about a reason
> 3. Used in questions to suggest that it is not necessary to do sth

---

The sentence

> Why can't I see?

is more applicable when you are asking a question [1].

---

The sentence

> Why I can't see?

will be considered grammatically wrong in this case.

---

However, if you want to talk about the reason behind it (make a statement[2] ), you can use

> why I can't see

in a sentence like this:

> That's why I can't see.

instead of

> That's why can't I see. (grammatically wrong)

---

But in some countries like Singapore, Hong Kong, etc,

it is alright to ask a question both way.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I see?

This is perfectly complete meaningful sentence and interrogative sentence.

> Why I can't see?

We can't use it in interrogative sentence. It is incomplete sentence.

> He doesn't know why i can't see.

It is completely meaningful sentence and not interrogative sentence.

> Doesn't he know why i can't see?

It is completely meaningful sentence and interrogative sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Question : Why can't I see ? For EG. This is a question that is genreally asked when you are able to see..
Statement : Why I can't See. For EG. This is a statement when you somebody is forcing you to not see anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? It doesn't really explain anything. What makes one a statement and one a question? How come *why*, a typical question word, is used in a statement?

Comment: You elaboration is incorrect. "Why I can't see" **alone** is not something one says when one's eyes are covered. A statement would be "Oh your hands are over my eyes! This is why I can't see." Without *this is* the rest is somewhat wrong.

Comment: I have already mentioned that this for an example.

Comment: Examples still need to be grammatically correct.