# What "xyz" is OR What is "xyz". Which is correct if I am not asking the question but trying to explain the answer?

Tags: grammar

If I want to tell the audience about the objective of the session and the objective is to understand "xyz", then what would be the appropriate statement to put in the slide?

**____________________________**

Objective:

To understand what is "xyz".

**______________________________**

***OR***

**______________________________**

Objective:

To understand what "xyz" is.

**______________________________**

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Why can't I see?" or "Why I can't see?"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62688/why-cant-i-see-or-why-i-cant-see)

Comment: @TimLymington If the solution to my question is similar to the one you have mentioned then the correct usage for me will be: To understand what "xyz" is. But having "is" at the end of the statement doesn't sound correct to me. Still if its correct please confirm this.

Comment: *To understand what "xyz" is.* is better than the first option (which is simply ungrammatical), but I agree it sounds a bit "ugly".  I would say "To understand xyz" or "To understand the meaning of xyz" or "To understand what we mean by xyz", or something along those lines.  In all of these, keeping "xyz" at the end of the sentence aids comprehension.

Comment: @max-williams Thanks! "To understand "xyz" " is definitely better. I will use that.